# How can I condense a Source Sans Pro font so the characters almost touch when 30px size?

Tags: fonts, css, web-fonts, kerning

I have a web site that is using the Adobe Source Sans Pro font.

On the website I would like to create a logo using this or a similar font but I would like to have it so there is almost no spacing between the characters. Is there a way that I can do this just with css or would I have to use another font?

If I need to use another font can anyone suggest an open source / free to use font that I could use for this.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a CSS property you could use: `letter-spacing`, which can also have **negative values**.

```
p {
    /* 16 * 0.0625 = 1px */
    letter-spacing: 0.0625em;
}
```

> The **letter-spacing** property controls the amount of space between each
>   letter in a given element or block of text. Values supported by
>   letter-spacing include font-relative values (em, rem), parent-relative
>   values (percentage), absolute values (px) and the normal property,
>   which resets to the font's default.

More info: [CSS Tricks on letter spacing](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/letter-spacing/)

---

If you only want to do this for the logo, you could have each letter in a separate span, and then apply a negative margin to the spans.

Something like:

```
span.letters {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-left: -3px;
}
```

---

Regarding the font choice, you could try with **[Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans)**.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Do you think there's any difference between Open Sans and Source Sans Pro?  I was really not sure what to use so picked the latter. But is one larger than the other or are there any other differences you know about?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it seems like there is always a minimum space between the letters and even putting the spacing at 0.0 will not change that.

Comment: You can also use negative values in letter-spacing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative letter-spacing to achieve that effect.

See this [example on codepen](http://codepen.io/kemie/pen/vEQjNO).